# Domain redirects to Plesk panel

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, redirect, dns, plesk

Yesterday I bought a website that had a script set up in it.
The script was written in ASP.NET MVH.
Needs windows hosting with minimum net 4.6 version.
Needs 1 MSSQL database.

When I go to my domain it opens Plesk login panel (https://example.com/login_up.php?success_redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F ).

I transferred the domain to my GoDaddy account, bought a Windows hosting and setup the nameservers.

Then I got the site files from the previous owner, I opened the zip and drag and dropped it all into my hosting and checked overwrite all. [image: website's files]

The problem started when all the files in .plesk folder gave an error "access denied" so I contacted the hosting firm and gave them my web site's files and asked them to do it for me. 20 minutes later tech support guy said he transferred my file into httpdocs.

(.rar file is still in httpdocs but also all the other files I transfered are still there but .plesk folder disappeared)

When I checked the website it gave an error "Login failed for user 'admin_b'.", under this was something like the logs of a console with a bunch of codes with some file directories. I reported this then they did something and "**BAM**" domain directs to Plesk panel.

They gave up and asked me to contact the script developer.

I don't get it, why would the domain redirect to Plesk panel?

Before I transfered the hosting everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please ping your domain first, is it point to correct IP address? It seems this is DNS issue, not server issue or your website problem. Please try first on your end